# Variable is assigned but never accessed

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and trying to do a simple count operation in a for loop:

```
public boolean play(Matrix matrix){
       int dimension = matrix.getDimension();
       int count=0;
       for(int x=0;x<dimension;x++){
           for(int y=0;y<dimension;y++){
               count++;
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
```

The error I get is related to count and is as in the title: Variable is assigned but never accessed.
The variable count should have been initialized outside the for loop and then accessed inside the for loop, I don't understand where the problem is located.

Comment: Please paste the actual error.

Comment: Furthermore give the calling method and content of matrix

Comment: @David Soroko Variable 'count' is assigned but never accessed

Comment: is that a compiler error or an IDE warning?

Comment: @David Soroko yes, IDE warning

Comment: You never _use (read from)_ the variable `count`, you just assign to it.

Comment: @David Soroko IDE warning

Comment: Then I think you have your answer in other comments.

Comment: @David Soroko I figured out, I'm new to java and come from c so I thought there was an error I was not aware of, thanks anyway

Comment: NP and good luck with Java!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like GriffeyDog wrote: You never use (read from) the variable count, you just assign to it. That was the problem.